# Check if port is blocked by windows firewall

Tags: vb.net, windows-firewall

How do i check if specific port is blocked by Windows firewall , both in incoming and outgoing connections.

I've seen code samples such as this one:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Dim host As String = "localhost"

Dim port As Integer = 6900

Dim addr As IPAddress = CType(Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)(0), IPAddress)

Try

Dim tcpList As New TcpListener(addr, port)

tcpList.Start()

Catch sx As SocketException

' Catch exception here if port is blocked

End Try

End Sub
```

But how can i know if the exception is thrown specifically because of firewall blocking, and not because of other socket errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the proper way to check if Windows Firewall is blocking a port isn't to test it, but to use the [Windows Firewall API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check conclusively.
I've never used it but I'd assume that [INetFwOpenPorts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be the place to start.

Here's a VB.Net [code sample](http://xplproject.googlecode.com/svn/tieske.xPL_check_package/tags/version_1_2_0_0/xPLHubVerifier/Firewall.vb) that seems to contain code that does this. Specifically I'd suggest looking at the `IsxPLportOpen` method in that sample which uses the [GloballyOpenPorts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to get a reference to `INetFwOpenPorts`.

Comment: Thanks, The VB sample was great!